# Add Static Lines on D3 Map Between Latitude and Longitude Points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 map of the world with markers on latitude and longitude points that I am interested in.

Now I would like to draw simple, static lines connecting these points.  How do I do this?

This is my code for the map with markers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var width = 900,
            height = 500;

    // Create Projection
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()

    // Generate paths based on projection
    var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

    // Create SVG
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

    // Group for the map features
    var features = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class","features");

    // Build map with markers
    d3.json("countries.topojson",function(error,geodata) {
        if (error) return console.log(error);

        //Create a path for each map feature in the data
        features.selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(geodata, geodata.objects.subunits).features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
        // Add markers for cities by their latitude and longitude.
        d3.csv("cities.csv", function (error, data) {
            features.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function (d) {
                        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
                    })
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .style("fill", "red");

        });
    });
</script>
```

`cities.csv`:

```
name,lat,lon
LA,34.05,-118.25
NY,40.7127,-74.006
```

This code produces something like this:

[image: Map with points]
Now I want to connect the markers with lines. Just a static line, doesn't need to be animated or anything. The result should look like:

[image: Map with points and line connecting points]

I added a new group for the lines above the `d3.json()` call:

```
var lines = features.append("g");
```

Then inside the `d3.json()` call, I add something like this to create the array of line coordinates:

```
   var theLines = [
                {
                    type: "LineString",
                    coordinates: [
                        [ data[0].lon, data[0].lat ],
                        [ data[1].lon, data[1].lat ]
                    ]
                }
            ];
```

But I'm not sure what to do next (or if my approach is correct) to actually add in the lines connecting the markers.

I want to use CSS to style the color and size of the markers and lines.

**Update:**

I tried changing the code for the circles to draw a line instead but its not working:

As per `srbdev's` answer, I changed `lineString` to `line` :

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function (error, data) {
    features.selectAll("line")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr("x1", function (d) {
                return projection([d.lon])[0];
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return projection([d.lat])[0];
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return projection([d.lon])[1];
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return projection([d.lat])[1];
            })
            .style("stroke", "red");
});
```

But I get the following result:  `x2` and `y2` have `"NaN"` values in the console.
[image]

Comment: The D3 way would be to construct data for the links (e.g. simply 2-element arrays with start and end city) from your `cities` data and use that to add lines. The easiest way to do that is probably to use `line` elements with the coordinates taken directly from the data in a similar way in which you're adding the circles for the cities at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Can you give me an example please?  I updated my question, I tried modifying my code to draw a line instead of the points.

Comment: Well how do you determine between which cities lines should be drawn?

Answer (score 1):

On your edit, you should change your code to:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function (error, data) {
features.selectAll("line")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", function (d) {
            return projection([d.lon])[0];
        })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return projection([d.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return projection([d.lon])[1];
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return projection([d.lat])[1];
        })
        .style("stroke", "yellow"); 
});
```

I changed "lineString" to "line". For a list of available SVG elements, see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element).

Another solution, though not really the D3 way as Lars mentioned, is to assign an ID to each of the circles and create your line as follow:

```
svg.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d3.select("#circle1").attr("cx"))
    .attr("y1", d3.select("#circle1").attr("cy"))
    .attr("x2", d3.select("#circle2").attr("cx"))
    .attr("y2", d3.select("#circle2").attr("cy"))
    .style("stroke", "yellow");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first solution. Its kinda working but I get some weird results. Please see my updated question with the new screen shot. x2 and y2 are returning "NaN, so the lines are both ending at the origin. Also its adding 2 lines for some reason.

Comment: I see... the reason it behaves so is because you use the d3.data and d3.enter functions which will draw the line twice, for each data point. You need to extract these data points and draw the lines directly without using the d3.selectAll, d3.data and d3.enter. For the line's attributes, use for example .attr("x1", data[0].lon), etc... If you can put your code in jsfiddle or something similar I could edit it for you.

Comment: Sorry use something like .attr("x1", function() { return projection(data[0].lon); }) for the line's attributes.

Comment: So i do this inside the d3.csv("cities.csv", function(){...}) that I used to make the points? or do I need to have a second d3.csv()?  I have tried both ways, but Im still getting some "NaN" values.  In the elements inspector, I see x1="NaN,247.38187319746223". Not sure why its setting 2 values for x1. Its setting 2 values for each x and y.  I'm having trouble getting a fiddle, I have no way to upload the countries.topojson file

Comment: Yes it would still inside the d3.csv("cities.csv", function() { ... }). It sounds like you're almost there but without seeing your data format from the callback, I can't tell for sure how to return your line attributes.